# How to access different elements in char** in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am given an array of strings in the form of a pointer to a pointer of a character (that is, char **). I wish to access each element in the array,

```
char **strings = {"hello", "bye", "whatusp"};

printf("%s\n", *(&strings));
printf("%s\n", *(&strings + 1));
```

I notice that the first printf() works, as it outputs "hello" for me, but the second doesn't output anything. The +1 does increment by 8 instead of 1, since the address is in bytes. How can I access an arbitrary element in such a double pointer?

Comment: Compiler won't be able to interpret this `char **strings = {"hello", "bye", "whatusp"};`

Comment: You can't do it statically, you will have to use `malloc`, at least for the first dimension.

Comment: This should cause a compiler error (and does for me). The only was to do this directly is to create `strings` as a 2D arrar: `char strings[3][8] = { "Hello", "Bye", "Whatusp" };`

Answer (score 1):

Just as simple as:

```
char *strings[] = {"hello", "bye", "whatusp"};

printf("%s\n", strings[0]);
printf("%s\n", strings[1]);
printf("%s\n", strings[2]);
```

Comment: I know, but I can't use the array notation. I must do it only with pointers and addresses

Comment: @VincentHan: Any restrictions that you have should have been mentioned in the question.

Comment: @VincentHan: `strings[2]` is equivalent to `*(strings+2)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the line

```
char **strings = {"hello", "bye", "whatusp"};
```

is wrong. If you want to declare an array of 3 pointers to [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), then it should be the following instead:

```
char *strings[3] = {"hello", "bye", "whatusp"};
```

In the previous line, you can omit the `3`, because the compiler is smart enough to count the number of elements itself, since you are initializing the array.

The lines

```
printf("%s\n", *(&strings));
printf("%s\n", *(&strings + 1));
```

are also wrong, because when using `printf` with the `%s` format specifier, you must provide a pointer to a string, i.e. a `char *`. However, you are providing a `char**` instead in both lines.

The expression `*(&strings)` will evaluate to a `char **` for the following reason:

The expression `&strings` will evaluate to a pointer to `strings`. Since `strings` itself is an array of 3 pointers to `char`, a pointer to `strings` is a pointer to an array of 3 pointers to `char`. Afterwards, you are applying the indirection operator `*` on this data type, so that the result of this operation is an array of 3 pointers to `char`. When passing this data type to `printf`, the array will [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) to a pointer to the first element of the array, i.e. to a pointer to a pointer to a `char` (which is a `char**`).

You should simply write the following instead:

```
printf( "%s\n", strings[0] );
printf( "%s\n", strings[1] );
```

The expression `strings[1]` is equivalent to `*(strings+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`char **strings` is a pointer to a pointer to char, not array of pointers to char, your compiler should have given you a warning anyways, if not you should enable them.

For that assignment to work, you will need to have an array of pointers, `char *strings[]` **or** if you want to use plain pointer notation *(array notation is using pointer arithmetic in the background though)*, you could dynamically allocate memory for the first dimension.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3

int main(void)
{
   char **strs = NULL;

   if ((strs = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char *))) == NULL) /* check malloc result */
   {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

  *strs       = "hello"; /* assignment makes sense in this case but you cant modify the string since its read-only*/
  *(strs + 1) = "bye";
  *(strs + 2) = "whatsup";

   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      puts(*(strs + i));
   }

   /* Alternative that will allocate space for each string if you need to store them or modify them later */

    /*  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      if ((*(strs + i) = malloc(YOUR_STRINGS_LENGTH)) == NULL)
      {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      
      snprintf(*(strs + i), YOUR_STRINGS_LENGTH, "string");

   }
   */

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am given an array of strings in the form of a pointer to a pointer of a character (that is, char **)

There is no such thing: a `char**` is just a pointer. It is not an array.
if `thing` is `char**` then
`*thing` is `char*` and `**thing` is, as declared, a `char`.

An array can be seen as a pointer, but a pointer is not an array.

note: the prototype for `main` is in general

```
    int main( int argc, char** argv)
```

so what you need to do is the same as every C program gets from the system.

#### Example

To have `char**` as an array of pointers to `char` you must build it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* array[] = {
    "I", "wish", "to", "access", "each", "element",
    "in", "the", "array"
    };

    int N = sizeof(array) / sizeof(char*);
    printf("%d strings in total\n\n", N);

    char** strings = (char**)malloc(N * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i=i+1)
        *(strings+i) = *(array + i);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i=i+1) 
        printf("%3d  %s\n", 1 + i, *(i + strings));

    // pointer is not an array
    char thing = '@';
    char* p = &thing;
    char** pp = &p;

    printf("\n\nthing is '%c', *p is '%c', **pp is '%c'\n",
        thing, *p, **pp);

    return 0;
}
```

#### output

```
9 strings in total

  1  I
  2  wish
  3  to
  4  access
  5  each
  6  element
  7  in
  8  the
  9  array


thing is '@', *p is '@', **pp is '@'
```

In particular note this lines

```
char** strings = (char**)malloc(N * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i=i+1)
        *(strings+i) = *(array + i);
```

where is defined that `strings` is an area of the needed size and than the pointers are initialized to the strings of the input array.